# Is it possible to left justify list items in a UL

Tags: html-lists

I have a basic unordered list except that I am using a list-style-type of none.  This removes the bullets from the list.  unfortunately it also right justifies the items in the list.  Is it possible to left justify the items in the list?

Comment: `ul {text-align: left;}` should work.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code

Answer (score 0):

I am actually confused about why they are being right justified. If I run a basic example in a fiddle they stay to the left.

If you want the `li`'s to move more to the left then just add `padding-left: 0;` to the `ul`'s class. If there is parent element that is applying the right justification then you can add `text-align: left;` to the `ul`'s children to override it.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrALD/2/).